# Distribute pip package no source code

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pip

I have an "homemade" python package which i can successfully install via pip package manager.

I'd like ti distribute it without giving the source code (*.py files)... i tried to compile them with

`python -m compileall .`

and then installed by typing `pip install .`

However it can't find the module when i try to import it in my application.

`ImportError: No module named...`

What do you suggest to solve?

Thanks

Comment: There are some steps missing, e.g. actually building the package.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174664/how-to-exclude-source-code-from-bdist-wheel-python). In short: you cannot do it with bdist_wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is to do with setuptools not packaging up `*.pyc` files, because normally you don't want them.

You should create a file `MANIFEST.in` with the content

```
global-include *.py[co]
global-exclude *.py
```

This tells setuptools to exclude `*.py` source files and include `*.pyc` compiled files.

Afterwards create a source distribution package

```
python setup.py sdist
```

or a wheel

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

which also compiles C extensions.

Comment: Thanks, something is moving on, but now i don't know how install the compressed file with *.py[co] files.

I have dist/package.tar.gz file but it hasn't setup.py file inside (i think according to manifest.in file) 

How should i proceed?

Comment: [Add another entry to `MANIFEST.in`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute) that includes `setup.py`.

Comment: MANIFEST.in does not affect what goes into the wheel.

Comment: That didn't help me at all. What helped me was the [commnet by Giuseppe]( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174664/how-to-exclude-source-code-from-bdist-wheel-python). This https://stackoverflow.com/a/57162139/1480131 actually worked for me.