# how to exclude source code from bdist_wheel python

Tags: python

We want to exclude the Python source code from the package we create. But after configuring `setup.py`, I failed excluding the py files. I have been using `python setup.py bdist_wheel` as command. Is there any way to exclude to source code from Python package? Basically we do not want to expose the source codes.

Comment: That's what a license is for. None of the existing Python tools will be much help to you, but I suspect you can encrypt your code and write your own import function..  Seems like a lot of work for very little gain though.

Comment: Yes...no help from the existing tools like bdist.thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The [wheel](https://github.com/pypa/wheel) plugin for `setuptools` that handles `bdist_wheel` does **not** have the `--exclude_source_files` which is only supported by `bdist_egg`. The `egg` packages are however deprecated and not supported by `pip` for example. What you can do however:

```
pip3 install wheel
python3 setup.py bdist_egg --exclude-source-files
wheel convert dist/mypackage-1.0-py3.6.egg
```

The `wheel` utility takes a source-stripped `egg` and converts it into `whl` package.

Comment: Nice hack, I've been searching for this for hours, I cannot understand why `bdist_wheel` doesn't have the `--exclude_source_files` option, so short sighted if you ask me. Anyway, on armhf debian 11 with `python3-wheel` installed, the `wheel` command is not installed. I needed to execute the convert command like this: `python -m wheel convert dist/....`

Answer (score 2):

This came up for us putting Python libs on an embedded system with very minimal available memory.

It can be achieved with:

```
./setup.py bdist_egg --exclude_source_files
```

Works for both distutils and setuptools.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we also encountered this issue (around 2 years ago) and didn't find a sensible automation process for it. So I wrote my own.

You're welcomed to it: [setup.py template](https://gist.github.com/ophers/093c31bce28f1356b7bf149a99e58326)