# Souce code getting packaged in python wheel

Tags: python-3.x, deployment, pip, pypi, python-wheel

We are using the wheels to deploy our code to QA/Production. Recently we found/realized that wheel packages are actually storing our source code. And by simple command as below will open all the source code inside it.

```
unzip package.whl
```

command used for wheel creation is as below

```
cd /path/to/source/code/folder
python setup.py bdist bdist_wheel
```

So,

1. Is there any way to create wheels which creates binary and stores in package rather than source code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to exclude source code from bdist\_wheel python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174664/how-to-exclude-source-code-from-bdist-wheel-python)

Comment: Yeah,,      The answers looks use ful. We are going with answer given by @kravietz , create eggs without source then convert them to wheel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the simplest sense, `wheel` is just:

- a zip file
- with a specific filename
- and a specific directory layout
- containing pure-Python source code
- and any platform-specific binaries

This means that a `wheel` (and any other distribution) is not a binary itself, but it may contain platform-specific binaries -- for example, if you are building/compiling some C code along with your Python package.

Most wheels are pure-Python, which means that they *only* contain Python source code.

It seems like you're asking how to "compile" Python code into an obfuscated binary. This is not the goal of a `wheel`. You might want to read more details on the `wheel` format here:  https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/

> Is there any way to create wheels which creates binary and stores in package rather than source code?

Not with the `wheel` format. If this is actually your goal, you may want to look into `pyinstaller`, `py2exe` or `cython`, depending on the target platform.

Answer (score 0):

In a case someone stumbles here the same way I did. If you

1. Use `Cython` to pre-compile your library.
2. Have not only `.pyx`, but also `.py` modules. For example you want to do this with some existing project without any modifications (except for `setup.py`), or consider it unreasonable to do in the first place as `Cython` consumes `.py` files also).
3. Want to distribute pre-compiled library without any `.py` files included (except for may be empty `__init__.py` files).

Then, you can apply the following (quite dirty) solution to exclude any files you want from the wheel:

```
from wheel.bdist_wheel import bdist_wheel

class CommandBdistWheel(bdist_wheel):
    
    # Called almost exactly before filling `.whl` archive
    def write_wheelfile(self, *args, **kwargs):
        dr = f'{self.bdist_dir}/<package name>'
        paths = [
            path for path in glob.glob(f'{dr}/**/*.py', recursive=True)
            if os.path.basename(path) != '__init__.py'
        ]
        for path in paths:
            os.remove(path)
        super().write_wheelfile(*args, **kwargs)

setup(
    # ...
    cmdclass={'bdist_wheel': CommandBdistWheel},
    # ...
)
```